# How to add image in DatagridView Column Header?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview. I create datagridview column in .cs page. I want to add image in a datagridview column header.

```
DataGridViewCellStyle columnHeaderStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
columnHeaderStyle.BackColor = Color.Beige;
columnHeaderStyle.Font = new Font("Bookman Old Style", 8, FontStyle.Bold);

datagridview1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle = columnHeaderStyle;
datagridview1.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells);
datagridview1.ColumnCount = 2;            
datagridview1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Details";
datagridview1.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Amount";
```

I want to add image in second column. That means "Amount(image)". How can I do this?

Comment: Lucas's Answer works nicely.

Answer (score -1):

you have to **store the images in a resource file**, then you can pull from it.

**Refer to below link for more details :**

[Datagridview Image Column Setting Image - C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8182071/datagridview-image-column-setting-image-c-sharp)

hope this helps..

Comment: This is not about the __Column Header__